# How to pass empty string to bash for loop

Tags: string, bash, for-loop

I want to pass an empty string as one of the values to a bash for-loop – like this:

```
for var in "" A B C; do
    ...
done
```

This works. However, I would like to store the possible values in a variable, like this:

```
VARS="" A B C
for var in $VARS; do
    ...
```

Here, the empty string is ignored (or all values are concatenated if I use `for var in "$VARS"`). Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't. Don't do that. Use an array.

This is a version of [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

```
VARS=("" A B C)
for var in "${VARS[@]}"; do
    : ...
done
```

And you almost *never* want to use an unquoted variable (like `for var in $VARS`).

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest using an array

```
#!/bin/bash

array=("" 1 2 "")

for i in "${array[@]}";do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Note: the quotes around *"${array[@]}"* are important, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: [Explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347130/why-do-we-double-quote-a-dollar-sign-evaluation-in-bash) for the previous comment.